# Где применить абстрактный класс и его свойства?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Создаю приложение в Qt для работы с базой данных. По заданию необходимо использованием абстрактных классов.
Например я хочу создать класс который связывается и работает с базой данных SQL и непосредственно при добавлении новой информации сразу добавляет информацию и в память и в TableWidget.

```
class DataBase{
  public:
    virtual void save() = 0; //Сохраняет информацию в SQL
    virtual void update() = 0; //Загружает из SQL таблицы и добавляет в память
    virtual void del(int index) = 0; //Удаляет какой-то index элемент таблицы
};
```

Ну и так далее, а затем создать какой-нить класс, который уже наследуется от `DataBase`

```
class StudentsData: public DataBase{
     private:
         vector<string> names; //имена студентов
         vector<string> lastnames; //фамилии студентов
         vector<int> marks; //оценки студентов
     public:
       //.. определить виртуальные функции .. //
};
```

То есть класс `DataBase` по сути абстрактный класс, который предназначен для работы с какой-то конкретной таблицей базы данных.
Я просто совсем недавно начал пытаться разбираться с абстрактными классами и хотел понять, правильно я их смысл понимаю, потому что в интернете нашел единственный с точки зрения логики пример про абстрактный класс фигуры. И есть предложения как сделать проще и лучше?

Comment: абстрактный класс позволяет выполнить код, не зная о каком наследнике идет речь(если очень коротко)

Comment: Это разве не интерфейс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысль абстрактного класса пропадает, если  предусмотрена реализация только одного потомка.  Что у вас не так?..  Скажу мое мнение:

Во первых `virtual void delete(int) = 0;` (тут излишне придать имя, поскольку обьект не используется).  Индекс какого вектора из трех имеется ввиду?.. Вы будете удалять из имени, из фамилии или из оценок?..  По этой причине и  для демонстрации  преимуществ абстрактного( интерфейсным называют не спроста) класса, разделим понятие  `StudentsData` на части. Именно такой подход позволяет разделять и властвовать...

Во вторых идентификатор `delete` это один из многих (скорее не очень многих) имен, который `нельзя использовать` в `C++` в целях, отличных от той, для чего он предназначен...(специалистам прошу это предложение  редактировать, если я неясно выразился)

```
class DataBase{
  public:
    virtual void save() = 0; 
    virtual void update() = 0; 
    virtual void del(int); 
    virtual bool size() const = 0;
};
class StudentsNames: public DataBase{
     private:
         vector<string> names; //имена студентов       
     public:
       //.. определить виртуальные функции .. del(int) можно не определять//
};
class StudentsLastNames: public DataBase{
     private:
         vector<string> lastnames; //фамилии студентов      
     public:
       //.. определить виртуальные функции .. del(int) можно не определять//
};
class StudentsMarks: public DataBase{
     private:
         vector<int> marks;  //оценки студентов     
     public:
       //.. определить виртуальные функции .. del(int) можно не определять//
};
//...    дальше можно добавить произвольное количество наследников,
//при этом перекомпиляция вашего кода  сведется к минимуму. 

void  implementation_code(DataBase* pb, int index)
{
    p->update();       // загружать
    if (p->size() > index) //если имеется больше index символов
    p->del(index);         //удалить (index + 1)- ый элемент
    p->save();         //сохранить результат
}
```

теперь можем функцию использовать для любого потомка, т.е. загружать, удалять  какой то элемент и сохранить результат имени или фамилии или оценки

```
 StudentsNames name;
 StudentsLastNames last_name;
 StudentsMarks marks;
```

и если для всех трех потомков определен  del(int)

```
 implementation_code(&name, 20);
 implementation_code(&last_name, 20);
 implementation_code(&marks, 5);
```

Вы вполне можете написать и подругому.  Все зависит от целей и вкуса. Можете добавить любое количество потомков, и это не станет причиной перекомпиляции кода и легко будет управлять обьектами этих типов.

P.S. уверен, что многие расскажут лучше, я попытался помочь как могу...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, пища для размышлений, конкретно del для 3 векторов я хотел использовать, ибо я работаю с конкретной таблицей в sql состоящей из столбцов: ИМЯ ФАМИЛИЯ ОЦЕНКА например, и если и удалять то всю строку столбца. Про delete в спешке написал, думаю компилятор бы пожаловался.